# Python script for analyzing pair separations in huge arrays

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, scipy, kdtree

I am writing a Python script to compare two matrices (**A** and **B**) and do a specific range query. Each matrix has three columns and over a million rows. The specific range query involves finding indices of A for each row of B (when A is compared to B) in such a manner that the the **pair separation distance** is in a **given range** (*e.g.* **15 units** < **Pair Separation** < **20 units**). (It doesn't matter which array comes first.) And then, I have to repeat it for other slices of pair separations, *viz.* **20 units** < **Pair Separation** < **25 units** and so on till a maximum pair separation range is reached.

I have read that **cKDTree** of **scipy.spatial** can do this job very quickly. I tried using cKDTree and followed by the use of **query_ball_tree**. The query_ball_tree returns output in the form of a *list of lists* and it works perfectly fine for matrices have ~ 100,000 rows (*small size*). But, once the size of the matrix (number of rows) becomes closer to a million, I start getting **memory errors** and my code doesn't work. Obviously, the computer memory doesn't like to store huge arrays. I tried using **query_ball_point** and that also runs into memory errors.

This looks like a typical big data problem. Time of execution is extremely important for the nature of my work, so I am searching for ways to make the code faster (*but, I also run into **memory errors** and my code comes to a grinding halt*)

I was wondering if someone can tell me what is the best method to approach in such a scenario.

: Is the use of scipy.spatial cKDTree and query_ball_point (or query_ball_tree) the best approach for my problem?

: Can I hope to keep to keep using cKDTree and be successful, using some modification?

: I tried to see if I can make some headway by modifying the source of scipy.spatial cKDTree, specifically **query_ball_tree** or **query_ball_point** to prevent it from storing huge arrays. But, I am not very experienced with that, so I haven't been successful yet.

: Its very possible that there are solutions that haven't struck my mind. I will very much appreciate any useful suggestion from the people here.

Comment: data statistics may make a difference in approach - are there any uniformity/distribution expectations, are the slices expected to be return a tiny subset or will the whole million be in the separation range(s)

Comment: While matrix A includes real coordinates (hence three columns), matrix B is a has random elements (also three columns) in such a manner that it samples all the coordinate space covered by matrix A. Typically, **matrix B** (random) is **50 times** larger than **matrix A**. I can think of pruning matrix B (if there is a smart way of doing this), but all elements (rows) in matrix A are relevant.